# recursive array menu php

Tags: php, hierarchy, recursive-query

How to build a php function that will convert this code into html menu
this is the post that i make to the function via ajax

```
list[0][id] 55
list[1][id] 69
list[2][children][0][id]    67
list[2][children][1][id]    68
list[2][id] 57
```

And here's the array that i get into the function

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 55
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 67
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 57
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 68
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 69
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i've tryed this function but it doesn't work

```
function tomenu($arr){
  $html = '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($arr as $v){
    $html .= '<li>' . $v['id'];
    if (array_key_exists('children', $v)){
      $html .= $this->tomenu($v['children']);
    }
    $html .= '</li>'.PHP_EOL;
  }
  $html .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
  return $html;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is that code even an array? I don't see any $'s or ='s just looks like text to me.

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not an error message. If it doesn't work, what does it do?

Comment: please show the php code that defines/initiates your array.

Comment: This is error: `$this->`. Just removed it!

Comment: sorry that's my mistake here's the php array that i get from the post

Answer (score -1):

```
function tomenu($arr) {
    $this->html .= '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        $this->html .= '<li>' . $v['id'];
        if (is_array($v['children'])) {
            $this->html .= $this->tomenu($v['children']);
        }
        $this->html .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $this->html .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    $returnVal = $this->html;
    $this->html = '';
    return $returnVal;
}
```

i have not tested this code though

Comment: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: in question there was $this->tomenu so i assumed this is a member function of some class... if it is then  my solution should work..

Comment: i use $this becouse that's how it's wroking on my controller please don't vote down what you'r not sure sorry if i didn't told ya it's a controller besides not the $this it's the problem